# Create frequency table using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given an numpy array of observations like:

`array([2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0)`

How can I create a frequency table for a range of numbers such as from 0 to 6 (including values which have a frequency of 0)? The output should look like:

`array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.], [5., 3., 3., 1., 0., 1., 0.]])`

where the first array are prespecified range of numbers and the second array are the counts. I have tried using
`np.unique(test2, return_counts=True)`, but that only returns values that have a count greater than 0.

Comment: Have you looked at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I haven't but I would like to do a line plot with the final output instead of a histogram.

Comment: And this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. I used `np.histogram`.

Comment: `collections.Counter` can also be used

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's `bincount` function should do what you need:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([2, 5, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0])

F = np.bincount(A,minlength=7)

print(F) # [5 3 3 1 0 1 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's `histogram` function should do what you need. Below is the example.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5)
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a, density=True)

#hist
#array([0.5, 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0.5])
#bin_edges
#array([0. , 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2. , 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 4. ])
```

Comment: Thanks. Why are there more bin_edges than elements in the array though?

Comment: @Jackdaw the bin_edges start with the leftmost edge and end with the righmost